# javascript Converting function to a generic form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

Disclaimer:  I am not looking for someone to code this for me just some pointers to help me fix this problem :)

I have the following web page that allows me to add fields dynamically to a form.  The current page works.  What I want to do is figure out how to make the javascript at the bottom of the page  more generic.  example I want to pass the templet id and the target id to the function without hard coding the templet id and the target id into the script.   Here is the code that I have and works just fine.

I want to make the morefields function so that I can reuse. I want to pass to the function the template and the target. example function moreFields ( templete, target). this way I can use the same function without editing over and over in different web pages. if you look in to the moreFields function you will see that it is hard coded for "readroot" and "writeroot" I want to change the function so it will take parameters and do the same thing it is doing now.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="generator" CONTENT=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">


  <TITLE></TITLE>
  <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
div.c1 {display: none}
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY >

  <DIV ID="readroot" CLASS="c1">
    Variable Name <INPUT NAME="VarName"><BR>

  </DIV>

  <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

    Function Name: <INPUT NAME="CFunction">&nbsp;<BR>


   Function Alias: <INPUT NAME="AFunction"><BR>
    <BR>
    <SPAN ID="writeroot"></SPAN> 
    Function return: <INPUT NAME="AFunction"><BR>

   <INPUT TYPE="button" ID="AddMoreFields" VALUE="Give me more fields!" ONCLICK= "moreFields()"> <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send form">
  </FORM>
<SCRIPT >      
var counter = 0;
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById("readroot").cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById("writeroot");
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
  window.onload = moreFields()
  </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: so if i understand it , you wan to simply add a text and input field right?

Comment: I want to make the morefieds function so that I can reuse.  I want to pass to the function the template and the target.  example   function moreFields ( templete, target).    this way I can use the same function without editing over and over in different web pages.   if you look in to the moreFields function you will see that it is hard coded for  "readroot" and "writeroot"   I want to change the function so it will take parameters and do the same thing it is doing now.